# "vcxsrv.exe: command not found" Error on WSL Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, software-installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xserver

I am a seismology student and I'm new to programming. Recently I tried to install ISP for seismology via the instruction mentioned in [this article](https://projectisp.github.io/ISP_tutorial.github.io/install/#installation-for-windows-users).

I installed WSL Ubuntu, then I installed vcxsrv.exe. Then I ran Ubuntu and pasted this command: `vcxsrv.exe -multiwindow -clipboard -wgl`. But I received  `vcxsrv.exe: command not found`. Why does this happen and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Why are you running a Windows executable in Linux?  you should be using a Linux binary for it.

Answer (score 1):

[Per the instructions](https://projectisp.github.io/ISP_tutorial.github.io/install/#installation-for-windows-users), you have to run the command `"C:\Program Files\VcXsrv.exe" :0 -multiwindow -clipboard  -wgl -ac` **from Windows**.

Only after this step should you run the commands from inside Ubuntu/WSL.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was helpful

Comment: I continued until step 6, which is: 6. Install normally ISP:

To run the installation go to ./isp/installation and type ./ISP_installer.sh

Just in case the alias isp do not open the software, go to ./ISP and type:

conda activate isp or source activate isp
python start_isp.py  but at this step I don't know how to go to   ./isp/installation. I tried commands below but for all I got the same error.